# Interpreting Char-Array to Multiple concatenated Datatypes

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, char, byte

I receive via Socket a stream of bytes (or chars in C++). Now I want to interprete them. I know which datatypes are hidden behind the bytes. My message looks somehow like that:

```
value1   --> char (1 byte)
value2   --> long (8 bytes)
value3   --> short (2 bytes)
...
```

How can I achieve the interpretation efficiently?

**//Edit: that don't work, the bytes don't describe characters but integers.**

I thought about doing is with memcpy and atoi (not tested so far):

```
char value1 = *charPtr;
charPtr++;

char value2[8]="";
std::memcpy(charPtr,value2,8);
long v2 = atoi(value2);
charPtr+=8;

char value3[2]="";
std::memcpy(charPtr,value3,2);
short v3 = atoi(value3);
charPtr+=2;
```

Comment: Have you considered using std::stringstream and its operator>> to get your data out?

Comment: the data in the char* are not characters, so I don't think that stringstream would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I figured out how to do this. The keyword is bit shifting:

```
long readAndSkipLong(char*& b)
{
    unsigned long ret = (b[0] << 56) | (b[1] << 48) | (b[2] << 40) | (b[3]<<32) | (b[4] << 24) | (b[5] << 16) | (b[6] << 8) | (b[7]);
    b+=8;
    return ret;
}

int readAndSkipInt(char*& b)
{
    int32_t ret = (b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8) | (b[3]);
    b+=4;
    return ret;
}

short readAndSkipShort(char*& b) {
    short ret =  (b[0] << 8) | (b[1]);
    b+=2;
    return ret;
}

...
while (readChar(it)!='#') // stop at the terminating char
{
        readAndSkipShort(it);
        readAndSkipInt(it);
}
...
```

Nevertheless my shifting for long and int seems not to be right. For the intended value

```
152  --> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10011000
```

I interpret:

```
-104  --> 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 10011000
```

any idea where the bug is?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to send data as raw byte stream, and you've been assured that sender and receiver uses the **same floating point format** and **same endiness**.

But your packed data stream apparently violates alignment rules on both sender and receiver sides, so we can not do something like `value2 = *(long *)data;`

So, try using `parsePackedStruct(data, &value1, &value2, &value3);`

where a  reasonable implementation can be:

```
void parsePackedStruct(char *data, char *pValue1, long *pValue2, short *pValue3)
{
    memcpy(pValue1, data, sizeof(*pValue1));
    data = data + sizeof(*pLalue1);
    memcpy(pValue2, data, sizeof(*pValue2));
    data = data + sizeof(*pLalue2);
    memcpy(pValue3, data, sizeof(*pValue3));
}
```

This requires your sender and receiver have strictly the same size for `char/short/long`, which seems too strict to me because size of `long` varies from platform to platform much more often than other arithmetic types. For the same reason, I'd also avoid `bool` and use `uint8_t`.

So consider C99 integer types like `int32_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming sender and receiver are in perfect sync as to the raw data sent/received, you could do something like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct MyPackedData {
  char c;
  long l;
  short s;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

...

```
MyPackedData parsedData;
memcpy(&parsedData, charPtr, sizeof(parsedData));
```